# Как сделать такие полоски для степпера?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Мне нужно сделать сделать такие прямоугольные блоки для отображения пройденных вопросов.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И что именно у Вас не получается?

Answer (score 2):

```js
let d;

let li = document.querySelectorAll('li')

let ul = document.querySelector('ul');
let div = document.createElement('div');

ul.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  let target = e.target;

  for( let i = 0; i < li.length; i++ ){

  }

  div.innerHTML = `Вопрос ${target.dataset.numer}`;
  ul.before(div);

  if( target.tagName != 'LI' ){
    return
  }

  targ(target)
}); 


function targ(select){
  if(d){
    d.classList.remove('yell')
  }
  d = select;
  d.classList.add('yell')
}
```

```css
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: gray;
  }
  .yell{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-numer='1'></li>
  <li data-numer='2'></li>
  <li data-numer='3'></li>
</ul>
```